# Return brace-enclosed initializer list as struct

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Giving below simplified code compiled with `g++ -c test.cpp` or `g++ -std=c++17 -c test.cpp`

```
#include <cstddef>

struct sd_bus_vtable {
        union {
                struct {
                        size_t element_size;
                } start;
                struct {
                        const char *member;
                        const char *signature;
                } signal;
        } x;
};

sd_bus_vtable get()
{
    return {
        .x = {
            .signal = {
                .member = "",
                .signature= "",
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It compiles fine on GCC 9.2.0 and clang 5/6, but fails on 8.3.0 or 7.4.0 with below error message:

```
test.cpp:25:5: error: could not convert ‘{{{"", ""}}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘sd_bus_vtable’
     };
```

To work around it, the function `get()` could be changed as below, but it looks not so clean...

```
sd_bus_vtable get()
{
    struct sd_bus_vtable t = {
        .x = {
            .signal = {
                .member = "",
                .signature= "",
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
```

The question is, is the above code valid or not? If yes, does it trigger some bug in GCC that is fixed in GCC9?

Comment: Actually I did use `-std=c++17`, the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designated initializer syntax is not in Standard C++ yet. It is scheduled to be included in C++20 however that has not yet been finalized or published.

So you are relying on the compiler supporting this upcoming feature as an extension.

In published C++ standards there is no way to give an initializer like this for a union member other than the first one .   (You can have a default member initializer in the class definition).

In the meantime the following code would work:

```
sd_bus_vtable get()
{
    sd_bus_vtable r{};
    r.x.signal = {"", ""};
    return r;    
}
```

*Note:* This method (using the assignment operator to switch the active member of the union) only works if all of the union members have trivial constructors and destructors. Otherwise you need to manually destroy and create .

Also it's possible to omit the name `x` (this is called *anonymous union*), then the names of the union members are accessible as if they were members of the enclosing struct.

Comment: So what is the preferred syntax to return a struct like that?

Comment: @Mine added an example

Comment: The C++20 draft has been finalized last week. I think it only has to go through the voting/approval process now, which seems to be considered a formality from what I can tell.

Comment: @walnut is there another one after N4849 or is that it?

Comment: @M.M I think there will be another one including last week's changes once they are edited in. [The draft repository](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue&utf8=%E2%9C%93) still has the motions as open issues.